# SQL Trouble working with long float numbers, math

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I  have 2 values in my inventory database.  One is the QtyOnHand (float), and the other is a calculation of all the inventory transactions for that item (think `SUM(TransQty)` where transQty is also a float).  Problem is, over time for unknown reasons some of these values fall out of sync.  So now I'm trying to clean them up.

Basically, I'm taking QtyOnHand (which we are declaring as accurate), and subtracting the transaction total from that.  Then making a correction entry into transactions for the difference.  This works great until we get to numbers with lots of "decimal dust".  Also, float seems to display `0` even in cases where the actual value is more like `0.0000000000000000237`.

Here are some data that I'm having trouble correcting.

[image: Example Data]

The items with scientific notation are giving me trouble.  Even the line showing Item PLXL-105-H, which shows -18, -18 is not displaying accurately, because my query is only returning values that are outside of 1% mismatch.  I've been working entirely in TSQL, would it help to manipulate the values from C# program?

So, here's my question: how should I handle these numbers?  I've tried converting them to DECIMAL(38,38), but that gives me arithmetic overflow.  I need to get an accurate value representing the difference, then use that value to balance things out.

Comment: in real life what does all that precision mean?

Comment: @Randy- Nothing, the smallest unit we work in is .1 (1/10).

Comment: can you just update the transbal to zero when the abs of the current value is < 1?

Comment: @Randy- No, I wish I could, but the transbal doesn't exist, its calculated from all transaction records.  That's essentially what the accountant wants me to do.

Comment: oh i see... and all transactions that go into the calculation are integers (stored as floats)? and it is not possible to change the database definition to int(?)

Comment: @Randy- No, no all integers (most are), but the most precise real value is 1 decimal place.  Yes, stored as floats.  Correct, can't change table.

Comment: how about using ROUND when you calculate the transbal?

Comment: I could use ROUND, it will get me closer, but won't allow me to balance out the insane decimals.

Comment: Well, one problem is that you are using `FLOAT` and then *declaring that as accurate*, it is not.

Comment: @Lamak- True, so I should convert that to deciaml(38,30) or something and use that?

Comment: @MAW74656 - Well, it is stored as `FLOAT`, so you already have inaccurate values on your database.

Comment: @Lamak- Right, but thats what exists.  So if we're going to use it as definitive, I'm thinking about converting and using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to make the entry?

Doing something like:

```
with to_update as (
     select itemNumber, QtyOnHand, TransBal
     from t
)
update tb_table
    set offset = TransBal - QtyOnHand
    from to_update
    where to_udpate.itemNumber = tb_table.itemNumber
```

should do the trick.

I sounds like you are trying to take the data out of the database, manipulate it, and then put it back in.  If you stay within the database, you won't have a problem, because the values never get converted to strings.

By the way, for the decimal conversion, you should use `decimal(38,19)` or something.  The scale parameter is for the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, so setting it to 38 only represents numbers between -1 and 1.

Comment: The question is tagged as sql-server-2000, so the CTE won't work here. Good point on the `DECIMAL` though.

Comment: Well, I definately was using Decimal wrong.  But I'm not trying to take the data out of the database and then put it back in, that was just a side question (would that be better?).  As I said in the OP, I'm working entirely in TSQL, SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Lamak- True, but I'm doing similar logic, just using variables to store the info.

Comment: Oh, I'm working in SSMS, so is the results pane there interpreting the float poorly?